# Push Notification icon for PWA

Tags: push-notification, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

For Progressive Web App's, when we push a notification to the mobile device; we get Chrome Browser icon in the Notification System Tray.
Can we have our custom icon there?

Is there any settings required in the manifest.json file?

Answer (score 10):

**I have found the answer to my question:**

We need to pass the property **badge** in the options notification object.
The value of the property **badge** is an URL to the image icon you want to show. It should be of right dimensions. This image is then masked accordingly by the device OS(Android/iOS)

More details about this property can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification)

Comment: I am using FCM, if I give badge with an app icon URL. it's throwing error. are you using FCM or other provider?

Answer (score 5):

The [showNotification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification) method has a parameter to specify an icon for the notification.

You can find an [example on the ServiceWorker Cookbook](https://serviceworke.rs/push-rich.html).